# UIPageviewController randomly displays view on top of its self.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm actually building an carousel. My objective is to make it generic, that means that I want it to be capable of receiving an array of controllers and with only that create the carousel(tacking in count that the UIPageViewController will show the controllers in the same order as the array).

What I have built so far is the controller that receives an array of controllers, and the generic controller that builds the basic screen.

The controller that manages the pages in an array is:

**BSRGenericOnboarding**

(.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BaseViewController;


#pragma mark - DELEGATE
//  Future Use
@protocol BSRGenericOnboardingDelegate <NSObject>
@required
@optional
@end


#pragma mark - DATASOURCE
//  Future Use
@protocol BSRGenericOnboardingDataSource <NSObject>
@required
@optional
@end


#pragma mark - INTERFACE

@interface BSRGenericOnboarding : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate ,UIPageViewControllerDataSource>


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BSRGenericOnboardingDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray               *pantallas;//  save screens

//  INIT HERE
- (instancetype)initWithArrayOfControllers:(NSArray *)arrayOfControllers
                       andCallerController:(BaseViewController *)callerController;


//  Close the onboarding
- (void)dismissOnboarding;

@end
```

(.m)

```
#import "BSRGenericOnboarding.h"
#import "BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController.h"
#import "BaseViewController.h"
#import "BSROnboardingCarouselButton.h"

#import "Constants.h"// Import screen measures and constants


@interface BSRGenericOnboarding ()

@property (nonatomic, weak)     BaseViewController      *BVC;//  contains the caller of this object

@property (nonatomic, strong)   UIPageViewController    *UIPageCV;

@end

@implementation BSRGenericOnboarding

#pragma mark - init

//  INIT
- (instancetype)initWithArrayOfControllers:(NSArray *)arrayOfControllers
                       andCallerController:(BaseViewController *)callerController {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.pantallas = [arrayOfControllers copy]; // getting screens!
        self.BVC = callerController;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - view Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //  add a self reference to screens
    [self addSelfToScreens];

    //  Init UIPageViewCotroller
    self.UIPageCV = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                    navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                  options:nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor           = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.UIPageCV.view.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.UIPageCV.delegate = self;
    self.UIPageCV.dataSource = self;
    [[self.UIPageCV view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];

    [self.UIPageCV setViewControllers:@[self.pantallas[0]]
                            direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                             animated:NO
                           completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.UIPageCV];
    [self.view addSubview:self.UIPageCV.view];
    [self.UIPageCV didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDelegate

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)pendingViewControllers {


}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    for(int i=0;i<self.pantallas.count ;i++)
    {
        if(viewController == [self.pantallas objectAtIndex:i])
        {
            if(i+1 < self.pantallas.count)
            {
                return [self.pantallas objectAtIndex:i+1];
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    for(int i=0;i<self.pantallas.count ;i++)
    {
        if(viewController == [self.pantallas objectAtIndex:i])
        {
            if(i-1 >= 0)
            {
                return [self.pantallas objectAtIndex:i-1];
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewController Utils

//  Cierra el onboarding
- (void)dismissOnboarding {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}


- (void)addSelfToScreens {

    for (BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController *screen in self.pantallas) {

        screen.onboardingUIPageVC = self;
    }
}

@end
```

The controller that is the base for all the screens is:

**BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController**

(.h)

```
#define INDEXDOTHIGH 15    //index button high
#define INDEXDOTWIDTH 15   //index button width
#define ESPACIADO 4        //index buttons spacing

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "BSRGenericOnboarding.h"
#import "BSROnboardingCarouselBar.h"

@interface BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController : UIViewController

//contains the reference to the BSRGenericOnboarding
@property (nonatomic, weak) BSRGenericOnboarding      *onboardingUIPageVC;

//contains the reference of the object caller of BSRGenericOnboarding
@property (nonatomic, weak) BaseViewController    *BVC;


@property (nonatomic, strong) BSROnboardingCarouselBar  *buttonsBar;

//Hide buttons bar
- (void)hideCasrousel;

//Show buttons bar
- (void)unhideCasrousel;

@end
```

(.m)

```
#import "BSRGenericOnboarding.h"
#import "BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController.h"
#import "BSROnboardingCarouselBar.h"
#import "Constants.h" // Constantes de tamano de pantalla

@interface BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView                    *backScreen;//  black screen for behind

@end

@implementation BSRGenericOnboardingScreenViewController

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.view];

    [self setCarouselBar];

    self.backScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
    self.backScreen.alpha = 0.9;
    self.backScreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.backScreen];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backScreen];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Index Carousel Dots
//Esconde el carousel
- (void)hideCasrousel {

    self.buttonsBar.hidden = YES;
}

//  Muesta el carousel
- (void)unhideCasrousel {

    self.buttonsBar.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)setCarouselBar {

    CGFloat buttonsBarX = center(SCREEN_WIDTH, ((INDEXDOTWIDTH * [self.onboardingUIPageVC.pantallas count]) + (ESPACIADO * ([self.onboardingUIPageVC.pantallas count] - 1))));

    CGFloat buttonsBarY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - INDEXDOTHIGH - 15;
    CGFloat buttonsBarW = INDEXDOTWIDTH;
    CGFloat buttonsBarH = INDEXDOTHIGH;
    self.buttonsBar = [[BSROnboardingCarouselBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonsBarX, buttonsBarY, buttonsBarW, buttonsBarH) numberOfPages:[self.onboardingUIPageVC.pantallas count] withEspaciado:ESPACIADO];

    [self.view addSubview:self.buttonsBar];
}

@end
```

This is how I call this onboarding:

```
- (void)createOnboarding {

    //  Onboarding Screens
    pag1ViewController *vc1 = [[pag1ViewController alloc] init];
    pag2ViewController *vc2 = [[pag2ViewController alloc] init];
    BSRComodinesSuperClubOnboardingScreen1 *vc3 = [[BSRComodinesSuperClubOnboardingScreen1 alloc] init];

     self.vc = [[BSRGenericOnboarding alloc] initWithArrayOfControllers:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3,nil]
                                                                    andCallerController:self];

    self.vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:self.vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The problematic is that when I'm scrolling the first page of the carousel, randomly sometimes the next page (foward page) apears in front of all the views like this photo show:

[The green background is the first view of the carousel, the yellow one is the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjQYz.png)

I searched this for days and I can't solve it by my own, this is the only thing that I can figure out, sometimes when the methods pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController: and pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController: are called, they bring the foward view but on top pf the carousel, showing 2 views at the same time, as the photo describes.

I want to know how can I solve this problem and if there is a simpler way to do what I've done.

Thanks a lot for reading!